# How do I pull in a new branch from a remote repo?

Tags: git, branch

I forked a repo on github but they than created another branch inside that repo. When I do git fetch upstream it does not create that branch in my repo. How do I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After you have done `git fetch` and gotten the new remote branch `origin/branchname` you can do

```
git checkout -t origin/branchname
```

This creates a local branch called `branchname` that tracks the remote branch.

If you know for sure that the name of the remote branch is exactly `origin/branchname`, and there is no other branch called `branchname` on any other remotes you have, you can use the shorthand

```
git checkout branchname
```

An alternative syntax can be used if you want to name the local branch something different

```
git checkout -b local_branchname -t origin/branchname
```

Comment: @user1809913, be sure to read [this](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) to understand why the approach explained by Klas is needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout <branchname>
```

Git automatically matches the branch names.